# HTML beginner with Javascript; code not running

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this code that I made in HTML involving javascript, but it's not running. Can someone point out what's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

function math() {
var a = 1;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var sum = 0;
for (var a = 1; a <10; a++) {
    sum = a+c;
    c = a+b;
    a = b;
}
alert(sum);
}
</script>  
</head>  

<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    math();
</script> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see an error in the console?

Comment: Why dont you tell us what is happening that you believe is in error.

Comment: Error check the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is running but you have created an infinite loop.

You always set `a = b` inside your for loop. Since `b` is equal to zero, the loop will never terminate because `a` is always less than 10.

Answer (score 3):

It's an infinite loop.

You are iterating over `a`, but you are changing it to `0` in the `for` loop so the script never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is an infinite loop. You never assign `b` to any value but 0. The final step in each loop, therefore, is assigning `a` to 0. `a` will never reach 10 and the loop will never break.

Answer (score 0):

Your will get a result of an infinite loop
You can't loop over a when you have set a equal to 0 inside your for loop ( a=b) and you know that variable b is equal to zero